# How to add a shape to a group with VBA in Visio

Tags: vba, visio, shapesheet

How can you add a shape into an existing group in visio, **without ungrouping** because I have many custom properties into my group shapesheet. I dont want subformulas using it to be broken.

Here is the beginning of my VBA code but I can't find a method to add the shape in the group.

```
Sub moveToGroup(OrigineShape As Shape, DestinationGroup As Shape)


End Sub
```

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was actually quite simple!

```
Sub moveToGroup(OrigineShape As Shape, DestinationGroup As Shape)
    OrigineShape.Parent = DestinationGroup
End Sub
```

Just remember not to use `Set` for this assignment, as doing so generates an error.